# No title node in Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck

I want to have a content type namely quote usign CCK. But quotes in general don't have a title. But since the title is a required field, how can I avoid being putting the title while creating a new node.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [Automatic Nodetitles module](http://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle), which should facilitate what you're looking to do.

Comment: Seconded. I've done this. (aribtrary name) node_id is what I tend to do in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to alter the form whose ID is `YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE_node_form`. For instance, assuming your content type is *quote*, then the form ID you'd want to alter would be `quote_node_form`. Here's a complete module that will make the *title* text field that you'd normally see

- Not required, and
- Hidden

We'll name the module *quotetitlenotrequired* (it may look a little clunky, but you should always try to avoid using underscores while naming your modules).

1. Make a folder (directory) inside the `sites/all/modules` called `quotetitlenotrequired`
2. Inside the `sites/all/modules/quotetitlenotrequired` directory, create one file named `quotetitlenotrequired.info` and another file named `quotetitlenotrequired.module`
3. Paste the following code inside the `quotetitlenotrequired.info` file:

   ```
   ; $Id$
   name = Quote Title Not Required
   description = Makes node titles not required for quotes.
   core = 6.x
   ```
4. Paste the following code inside the `quotetitlenotrequired.module` file:

   ```
   <?php
   // $Id$

   /**
    * @file
    * Makes node titles not required for quotes.
    */

   /**
    * Implements hook_form_alter().
    */
   function quotetitlenotrequired_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
     if ($form_id == 'quote_node_form') {
       $form['title']['#required'] = FALSE;
       // Remove the next line if you still want the title field to be visible
       $form['title']['#type'] = 'hidden';
     }
   }
   ```
5. After you've saved both files, go to `www.yoursite.com/?q=admin/build/modules`
6. Scroll down and check the box next to the *Quote Title Not Required* module (it should be listed under "Other")
7. Scroll all the way down and click *Save configuration*

Now, when you go to create a new *quote*, the title should no longer be required. And if you left the line there that says `$form['title']['#type'] = 'hidden';`, the whole title portion should no longer appear on the form.

Hope that helps...

:)